# UITextView becomeFirstResponder crash with EXC bad access

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I have a `UIViewController` with `UITextView` in the storyboard I assigned it with strong variable.The first time when I present the ViewController using story board segue there is no crash but when I dismiss the `ViewController` and again present the `ViewController` for the second time after `[UITextView becomeFirstResponder]` is called the app crashes and shows the following error

```
[UIViewController _responderWindow]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I have assigned delegate to the `ViewController` in which the TextView is added and implemented all the delegate methods

I tried calling this method `[UITextview becomeFirstResponder]` after a delay
but no use it was still crashing

I tried profiling with zombie template the error is in `UIKit`

this is the response I am getting when the app crashed if enable zombies in the product scheme

```
[ReviewViewController _responderWindow]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14ed3a2a0
```

this is the code I am using to present the viewcontroller which has the textview

```
[_promotionsViewControllerDelegate performSegueWithIdentifier:@"testing" sender:nil];
```

textview viewcontroller

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad { 
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _reviewTextView.delegate = self;
        [_reviewTextView becomeFirstResponder];
        }
```

this is the back trace error log when i run the application without zombies

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x758d4, 0x000000019271bbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x174697260)
    frame #0: 0x000000019271bbd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
    frame #1: 0x000000018675f96c UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _firstResponder] + 24
    frame #2: 0x000000018675f940 UIKit`-[UIResponder isFirstResponder] + 32
    frame #3: 0x0000000186e96ed8 UIKit`-[UITextView _keyboardDidShow:] + 32
    frame #4: 0x0000000181f58ae4 CoreFoundation`__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
    frame #5: 0x0000000181e97220 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 2060
    frame #6: 0x0000000182d96cc0 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
    frame #7: 0x0000000186e5f458 UIKit`-[UIInputWindowController postEndNotifications:withInfo:] + 580
    frame #8: 0x0000000186e60c7c UIKit`__77-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:]_block_invoke595 + 396
    frame #9: 0x000000018679c0a4 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 408
    frame #10: 0x000000018679bc0c UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 188
    frame #11: 0x000000018679bb14 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 104
    frame #12: 0x00000001860c0f64 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 296
    frame #13: 0x00000001002b4df0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #14: 0x00000001002b975c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1056
    frame #15: 0x0000000181f69fa4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    frame #16: 0x0000000181f6804c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1492
    frame #17: 0x0000000181e950a4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    frame #18: 0x000000018b0375a4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
    frame #19: 0x00000001867ca3c0 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
  * frame #20: 0x00000001000c1030 WineDisciples`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd83a58) + 116 at main.m:14
    frame #21: 0x0000000192d76a08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I Kindly request you to help me on this thanks..

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Identifier in inspector window similar to given in code (i.e. "testing" )?

Also in your .h file had you given the  . If not then add it.

Comment: i have used a seperate viewcontroller for testing purpose and i have given the same "testing" in the inspector also..

Comment: But if i try simulating the same scenario in other project it is not crashing.. So i tried having sepeate navigation controller and those storyboard files are not linked with any custom classes.. I have a textview in rootviewcontroller and another viewcontroller with textview which i a pushing through story board segue using a button action.. I edit the textview in root view controller and go the next scene and edit there come back tried to edit the application crashed with the same error. I am stuck with this for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but I had the same problem and the solution was to send remove from superview in the dealloc method of my vwc

```
deinit {
    self.commentTextView.delegate = nil
    self.commentTextView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```